# Is a chi-square test sufficient to test for a significance difference for my data?

Tags: r, excel

I am working on a project about what behaviour humpback whales show in a certain area along the coast of Mozambique. Now I am trying to test the significance, whether this behaviour is random through out the season or not. I thought of using an one way Chi-square test in either Excel or R, but I am unsure what the best way is.
I have 5 categories of behaviours (Breach, Back arch, Blow, Pectoral fin slap and Fluke up Dive). The data for the behaviour is per hour of observation. For example, on DOY 208 Back arch has been seen 1 time in 2 hours of observation, so the BR/HR is 0,5.
Would an one way Chi-square test be sufficient to test the significance? And would it be better to use R or Excel?
I am not very good at statistics nor do I have much time to analyse everything. So, a simple test that is easy to analyse would work best for me in this situation.

I have tried to use the `=CHISQ.TEST` in Excel but this did not show what the example online showed me. An online tutorial told me to calculate the expected data, but I am unsure if I did it correctly. The expected data was the sum of the observed data, divided by the total number of recorded data. So for my data that was 140,0471546/183=0,76112584. See the link for a screenshot of my excel too.

[image]

Comment: A test statistic of the form $\sum \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$ is explicitly for *counts*. It will not be suitable for rates or proportions. If you want to work directly on those you would need to alter the formulas accordingly. You should make your specific research hypothesis (/question of interest) explicit; it needs to be about population quantities, and should in no way contain the word "significant". ... which is to say (omitting all statistical jargon words) what, exactly are you trying to find out?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am trying to figure out wheter the behaviours that are recorded are random through out the season (DOY) or that they have a pattern.

Comment: Have a pattern in the sense of whether the proportions in each of the recorded behaviors change across time?

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, would never use Excel for statistical analysis. It is possible to do good analysis in Excel, but it's hard. And it's hard to save things. And it's easy to go wrong (and, while I am not sure, I think you have).  I don't like point-and-click analysis.

I also would not do chi-square. But, before I write what I might do, I note that you say:

> I am not very good at statistics nor do I have much time to analyse
> everything. So, a simple test that is easy to analyse would work best
> for me in this situation.

Well .... I'm sorry, but I think you should hire a statistician (or, if you are in academia, find one who wants to be co-author in exchange for doing the analysis). This is not a simple thing to analyze well, and you're not going to learn enough to do it right in a short time. Take a few statistics courses in grad school and then you may be ready.

I know this sounds harsh. But consider:

"I have to amputate a person's leg. I've never done it before, but I did take a course in anatomy. Which You-Tube should I look at? Should I use scalpels?"

or

"I have to cook a 5 course dinner for 20 people, but I'm not good at cooking. Should I use the stove or the oven?"

or similar. Ridiculous, right?  Well .... Same here.

But, suppose you really need to do this now, you can't afford a statistician, you aren't in academia, and you don't really care if it's the best analysis. Yes ... You can use chi-square. You can even use Excel (R is great, but it does have a learning curve).  But .... look at the formula for chi-square:

$\chi^2 = \sum \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i} $

That is, for each cell, find the observed value, calculate the expected value, take the difference, square it, then divide by the expected value and then add them all up. THEN you compare that to a chi-square distribution for the appropriate degrees of freedom.

Oh, and the expected value for each cell is the row total times the column total divided by the grand total.

I'm sure this can be done in Excel, but I am not sure how (and one of the problems with Excel is that it is hard to tell people how, even if you know).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am unable to hire a statistician and I have taken courses on Statistics, using SPSS. However, I am open for suggestions on what other tests I could use.

Comment: @glen_b is correct, you can't use chi-square for rates. You would have to convert to counts.   But I would use some form of regression here.